# Is it possible to get form data after redirect from login page using spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have an application where user sends form with id's on button click. If the user clicks on the button after session expires, it will redirect to login page. After login i am able to redirect to the post URL, but the form data id's are not present. Is there any way to do this?